# Risk Matrix Formula Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I am trying to get it so that the Impact column is auto-populated with the text in the below matrix when the user selects a value from both dropdown menus.

As you can see I've tried using Index/Match functions but I'm not convinced this is the right function for what I'm trying to do. I've also tried multiple If statements with And functions to define the ranges (e.g. =IF(AND(<=4,>=8), "Medium").

As a code example, here is the IF statement I've tried but cannot make work:

`=IF(LEFT(B3,1)*LEFT(C3,1)<=3,"Low",IF(LEFT(B3,1)*LEFT(C3,1)AND(>3, >=8),"Medium))`

Obviously, this continues on with the ranges for High and Very High.

Apologies in advance if I'm doing anything really basically wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Example Matrix]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INDEX(INDEX($H$11:$L$15,,MATCH(B3,$H$10:$L$10,0)),MATCH(C3,$G$11:$G$15,0))
```

Result:

[image]